# How to highlight the compilation buffer?

Tags: compilation-mode

I try to define a custom coloring of the compilation buffer, but I can not get the highlight correctly.

```elisp
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'my-message)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
  '(my-message
    "^\\(\\(ERRR\\|CRIT\\|ALRT\\|EMRG\\)\\|\\(WARN\\|NTCE\\)\\|\\(INFO\\|DEBG\\)\\) .*\\[\\(\\([^ \n]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)\\)\\]$"
    6 7 nil (3 . 4) 5))
```

This correctly colors the hyperlink:

[image]

But I can not get the beginning of the line right. I would like the tags `WARN`, `INFO`, `NTCE`, `DEBG` and `ERRR` to have the same color as the hyperlink. But everything I tried did not work. I get either the error, that the match does not exists of the color for all lines is fixed.

How to color the beginning of the line in the same color like the hyperlink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding some additional `HIGHLIGHT` parameters to your list should do it. As stated in Emacs' documentation for the variable `compilation-error-regexp-alist`:

> Additional `HIGHLIGHT`s take the shape `(SUBMATCH FACE)`, where
>   `SUBMATCH` is the number of a submatch and `FACE` is an expression
>   which evaluates to a face name (a symbol or string).

In your case, it should reduce to something like the following:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
             '(my-message
               "^\\(\\(ERRR\\|CRIT\\|ALRT\\|EMRG\\)\\|\\(WARN\\|NTCE\\)\\|\\(INFO\\|DEBG\\)\\) .*\\[\\(\\([^ \n]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)\\)\\]$"
               6 7 nil (3 . 4) 5
               (2 compilation-error-face)
               (3 compilation-warning-face)
               (4 compilation-info-face)))
```

---

Another, more verbose solution might be to define multiple regular expressions for your different levels, so that all groups always match.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'my-message-error)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'my-message-warning)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist 'my-message-info)
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
     '(my-message-error
       "^\\(ERRR\\|CRIT\\|ALRT\\|EMRG\\) .*\\[\\(\\([^ \n]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)\\)\\]$"
       3 4 nil nil 2
       (1 compilation-error-face)))
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
     '(my-message-warning
       "^\\(WARN\\|NTCE\\) .*\\[\\(\\([^ \n]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)\\)\\]$"
       3 4 nil 1 2
       (1 compilation-warning-face)))
(add-to-list 'compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist
     '(my-message-info
       "^\\(INFO\\|DEBG\\) .*\\[\\(\\([^ \n]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\)\\)\\]$"
       3 4 nil 0 2
       (1 compilation-info-face)))
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. But it is always just one match defined of the matches 2, 3 and 4. The others are undefined. And in that case Emacs complains about the fact, that I have specified a highlighting definition for an undefined match.

Comment: Well, it works in my settings (emacs 24.5.1). Which version are you using? Have you tried using `emacs -q` to check whether some setting in your init file might be responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: You are right. I thought I did it as you told me, but obviously I did something different.